# Dropdown terminal showing different font type. How can I correct this issue? (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, DE - Ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, fonts, settings

Today I saw something strage when I opened dropdown terminal and the font style is different in it. I do not know how this may have occured, but how can we solve this? I am attaching a picture to make it clear:

[image]

I want to remove as many icons and extension as possible, so I decided to use terminal by dropdown terminal extension. But this font style is not compact and I wish it were same as when we open terminal normally. If someone knows how to correct this, please help me. Thanks. :)

P.S. I am unable to open preferences and settings for drop down terminal because right click shows only two options - 1. copy 2. paste in dropdown terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Wiki for the project](https://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal/wiki) has this little tidbit:

> #### Changing the font
>
> For the moment, Drop Down Terminal uses the system monofont as font. To change it, use: gnome-tweak-tool → Fonts

Perhaps you could [open a feature request](https://github.com/zzrough/gs-extensions-drop-down-terminal/issues) with the developer?

Comment: I made all the fonts same in fonts using tweak but the dropdown terminal still has this strage font. I will have to follow this above link it seems. Thank you. :)

Comment: One moment. Now I changed and it is showing what is se in tweks - fonts. Thank you very much. :) However dropdown terminal must show the fonts set in preferences of terminal. Opened an issue on the link you gave but I shold have posted that on Pull request right? It was mmy mistake, edited it. :)